# spring oauth2 server grant by password Access is denied (user is anonymous)

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I try to setup a authserver, but when it get token in Advance rest client,it can't grant by password and input basic user and password  Access is denied (user is anonymous)

```
2017-03-23 21:18:56.788[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.788[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request 'GET /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.789[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.789[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request 'GET /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.789[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No matches found
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.789[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.790[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.790[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.792[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.795[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.796[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.796[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Requested session ID 72A53EBFC2683D7F4CEAF0BF51D76993 is invalid.
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.796[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.796[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=reader&password=reader; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.798[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.804[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5f5f5614, returned: -1
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.814[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]

[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.819[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.820[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request '/oauth/token' matched by universal pattern '/**'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.820[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.820[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.820[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher [0;39m [2m:[0;39m matches = true
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.820[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@78e22d35, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.825[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m httpRequestMediaTypes=[]
[2m2017-03-23 21:18:56.826[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7000[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7777-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not match any media types
```

here is my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class AuthServiceApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
         return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//    @Autowired
//    private DataSource dataSource;


//    @Autowired
//    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth
//                .jdbcAuthentication()
//                .dataSource(dataSource);//设置为从数据库读取用户认证信息(JdbcUserdetailsService)
//    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http.anonymous().disable()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .anyRequest().authenticated();

//        http
//        .csrf().disable()
////            .exceptionHandling()
////            .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
//        .and()
//            .authorizeRequests()
//            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
//        .and()
//            .httpBasic();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/**", "/login", "/signup", "/forgotPassword").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.configure(auth);
        auth
//      .parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("reader")
        .password("reader")
//        .authorities("FOO_READ")
        .roles("USERS")
        .and()
        .withUser("writer")
        .password("writer")
        .authorities("FOO_READ", "FOO_WRITE");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/hystrix.stream/**", "/info", "/error");
    }
//  @Bean
//  @Override
//  protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return super.authenticationManager();
//  }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

AuthServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
//  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

//    @Autowired
//    InMemoryTokenStore tokenStore;



//  @Bean
//  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
//      return new InMemoryTokenStore();
//  }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.configure(endpoints);
        endpoints
//        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.configure(clients);
        clients.inMemory() // 使用in-memory存储
                .withClient("client") // client_id
                .secret("secret") // client_secret
                .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password");// 该client允许的授权类型
//              .scopes("read", "write", "trust"); // 允许的授权范围
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.configure(security);
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
//      security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");//公开/oauth/token的接口
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing roles and authorities?